# php script to write to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and have written the following php script to write from a FORM. However, the database is not updating. I know that the database connection is okay. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$lastName = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO club.users (name, last_name, email, location, created_at) VALUES ('$name', '$lastName', '$email', '$location', '$timestamp')";
```

Comment: Where you are executing the query? And what is the table name (club.users)? Post complete code.

Comment: The code you've posted makes no effort to execute the INSERT statement. If you don't execute it, how do you expect it to actually do anything?

Comment: The file is a php file caled registration.php. It is called from action="registration.php" from the html form page

Comment: Where the code is located or where it is called from is irrelevant. The INSERT statement won't do anything if it is never executed, and your code does not execute it. *I have this menu for a great meal that I wrote down on a piece of paper, but no matter how long that piece of paper sits on my counter the food doesn't appear on my plate.* You may have assigned a great INSERT statement to a variable, but that statement won't change anything in the database untili it's actually run.

Comment: What everyone's trying to say is that there isn't any `mysqli_query()` call or `$stmt->execute()` call or whatever it may be in your question. Since that part is not posted, it's just a simple `$sql` variable that tells us nothing about why the code is not working (why the insertion is failing). We could just assume you never made that part, and then the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: Okay..I will try and read up first. Its just that I have literally spent days on this with no luck.

Comment: Or just add to the question to show more code that you've tried...

Comment: I agree with @JayA.Little, just post the rest of the code. The problem is most likely there anyway.

Comment: You should call  mysql_query for this or can you please provide more details for your question.

Comment: @rncjay, Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @Narendra Verma Not yet.. but will do so today. Thanks

Comment: @Narendra Verma The code worked perfectly for me. I used the 2 php files (register.php and connection.php) as you suggested. Just a question. is the database credentials which is in connection.php safe?

Comment: @rncjay, Yes, the connection.php file is safe. If anyone tries to use it the file then it will display only blank page.

Comment: @Narendra Verma Thanks heaps. Your help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

You have to use the SQL injection for security something like this

```
$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

Check your table name.I haven't use table name `club.users` before because it will display the error like table does't exist. Just use the table name `club` or `users`

Time to learn the PHP

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

**index.php**

I hope your HTML code looks like this

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST" name="register">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

**Connection.php**

If you are working on the local server the used root as username and password should be blank.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";//if you are working on local server 
$password = ""; //set blank if you are working on local server
$dbname = "myDB";//your database name

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**register.php**

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');// added the connection here
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
    $lastName = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
    $email =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $location = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["location"]);
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       $sql = "INSERT INTO club (name, lastname, email, location, created_at) VALUES ('$name', '$lastName', '$email', '$location', '$timestamp')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
        }

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all define the db server connection in same php page or you may include the connection. Php file for this purpose.

Secondly it you wish to use MySQL db simple use musql_query($sql, $con) then write below lines of after inserting results. 
Sorry I posted it from my mobile if you need I can post you entire code sample from my PC.